# How to create draft mail in a delegated account mailbox

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I have aliased a delegated mailbox account (let's call it delegateAccount@anywhere.com) to my main Google account and written a Script which use GmailApp.createDraft to create an email and store it in the Draft folder, like this:

```
GmailApp.createDraft('delegateAccount@anywhere.com', 'mailSubject', '', {
  htmlBody: 'html Mail Body',
  bcc: mailBccList,
  from: 'delegateAccount@anywhere.com',
  name: 'Delegate Special Name',
  replyTo: 'delegateAccount@anywhere.com'
}
```

This correctly creates the email... in my main account mailbox Draft folder, which is not what I want.
The objective of this project is to have all email from this delegate account in its own mailbox, the draft ones being the first part of the job.
Of course, it perfectly works if I'm creating emails by hand in the mailbox of this delegated account.

So, did I miss something ? is there a way to create a draft email directly in the mailbox of a delegated account ?
Thx

P.S. don't know if it is important but this delegated is a generic email account (without a real google account).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may be getting confused with what a delegated account has access to.

There is a really good explanation in this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/cant-send-email-on-behalf-of-delegated-email-address) about what you are allowed to do when you have a delegated account. As it's mentioned it could be possible to do what you are looking for if you use the delegated email address using the "Send mail as" feature.

The script you currently have is working as it's generating the draft successfully however it's only affecting your primary account.

Comment: Thx for your answer Gabriel.
I saw this thread before and I agree with it, except maybe this point:   
"Account delegation doesn't allow you to send emails from the delegated accounts email address (B) from within the primary account (A) - you need to switch to the delegated account first."
I can create an email in A and choose B in the 'from' field. But, it's right, it doesn't store my email in the Sent folder of B.  
Another difference is that I do not have to logout from A to access B mailbox. I just have to select the account in the top right account area...

Comment: To be more accurate, it's not that "I do not have to logout from A to login B" as B is a  generic account with no possible login in.

Comment: I believe that you are looking for this feature instead: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370 

Once you add the email alias you should be able to send the email using the sample to send emails with an alias: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getaliases

Comment: I think this is already what I did: create an email from an alias (delegateAccount@anywhere.com is an alias as per my accounts settings) -- My concern is that I would like that the created email is stored in the alias & delegate account mailbox, not in the primary account one. I can do it by hand without further constraints, can I do the same in a script ?